# How to mark important lines(change the font color) of pdf file text?

Tags: pdf

HI ALL,

I have one Big pdf file.Now i want to mark some important lines of the pdf file by changing background color or font color of the pdf file.Is there any tool available to do this?

Does anybody knows please suggest me also?

Thanks & Regards,
P.SARAVANAN

Comment: http://answers.yahoo.com/ is the community for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want only a Program to mark lines in PDF-Files? 
The Foxit Reader can do this.
http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/